# Standalone or Enterprise CA - what do I have?

Tags: windows, certificate-authority

When you install a Windows forest CA you have the option to make it standalone or enterprise. I have an existing installation which I am assuming is standalone as it doesn't have a certificate templates folder when I load the management console.

However, I can't find anything that definitively says "This is a standalone CA", such as under an "About" option in the management console. For all I know this could be a malfunctioning enterprise CA. How do I definitively tell whether my CA is standalone or enterprise?

Cheers

Comment: What version of Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does [this thread](http://www.1-script.com/forums/Enterprise-Sub-ordinate-or-Standalone-article10649--19.htm) help you? Looks like you were on the right track.

Quoting Jediah L. in the previously mentioned thread:

> A Standalone will be a root CA that is not subordinated (contains a 
>   self-attested certificate), and is not integrated into active directory at 
>   all. If it's integrated into active directory you will be publishing the 
>   root CA information into active directory and using LDAP as publication and 
>   distribution points.

Looks like a lot of good things [return with a Google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=tell+whether+my+CA+is+standalone+or+enterprise).

Answer (score 4):

Either of the following methods should work:

1. Run the `certutil` command:

   `certutil -getreg ca\catype`

   The output will tell you whether this is an Enterprise or Standalone CA:
   [image]
2. Alternatively, you can check for the presence of the Certificate Templates node. If Certificate Templates is present, then this is an Enterprise CA (Standalone CA's don't use templates):
   [image]

([Link to Reference](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/83e759aa-b93f-4c9b-a7d2-955daf751c9a/is-ca-a-standalone-or-enterprise-ca?forum=winserversecurity))